# Mapped Super Class and Many to Many cannot work together

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi my data model is like this: Item 1 and Item 2 have shared same properties and I put in class AbstractItem. Now I have a Container class which contains multiple items of either type Item 1 or type Item 2. And my source code is shown below

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public AbstractItem() {
    }
}
@Entity
public class Item1 extends AbstractItem{
    public Item1() {
    }
}

@Entity
public class Item2 extends AbstractItem {
    public Item2() {
        super();
    }

}

@Entity
public class Container {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<AbstractItem> abstractItemList;
}
```

I got following errors during compilation. The list of items is very important so I want to keep the list in Container class. Could anybody suggest what to do?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xyz.abc.model.Container.abstractItemList[com.xyz.abc.model.AbstractItem]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xyz.abc.model.Container.abstractItemList[com.xyz.abc.model.AbstractItem]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `AbstractItem` is not an Entity it's a `MappedSuperclass`.

So you cannot use `AbstractItem` in `@ManyToMany`.

Either use one of the types or if you want to use inheritance then you have to use `@Inheritance` instead of `@MappedSuperclass`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public class AbstractItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public AbstractItem() {
    }
}
```

The default inheritance strategy is SINGLE_TABLE so all entities of the inheritance hierarchy will be stored in the same table.
There are other options. Have a look at https://72.services/inheritance-in-jpa/